# Power on and start a terminal automatically at a specified directory

Tags: macos, terminal, login-items

I can open another terminal from a terminal with this command:

```
open -a terminal
```

Also, I can start a terminal at a specified directory

```
open -a terminal ~/Desktop
```

I intend to make the computer do it automatically after I power on the machine. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the most elegant way, but you could make an Automator `Application` with this command and set the app to open on startup by adding it to the login items in System Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in two steps:

1. **Open terminal on log-in**

   To do this, go to Apple menu > System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items and add terminal there.
2. **Run a specific command when terminal is launched**

   Open Terminal, go to Settings > Profile > Shell and in the first box write the command that you want terminal to run. In your case something like `cd ~/Desktop`.

Answer (score 1):

**Mac Ventura**  location of Login Items has changed.

1. **To open terminal on login**
   Go to Apple Menu > System Settings > General > Login Items > Open at Login > + (located lower left) > Applications (should be under Favorites on left) > Utilities > Terminal
2. **Run specific command on startup**
   When terminal has the focus, Open Terminal Settings with **⌘,** then
   Select > Profiles > Shell.
   Under Startup check the Run command box and enter desired command in the text box, ie. **cd ~/Documents**

Answer (score -1):

Enable auto-login, create a .sh script that does what you want and then add it to the startup items of the user that gets automatically logged in. If there's no concern about security that's how I might do it.